# Can formulas like these be solved easily by a javascript?

Tags: javascript

147 ? 53 + x * 36 = 7416

15 - 12 ? x * 2 = 32

The ? can be either +, * or -

I would need to get both the value for x and for ?

Is this trivial or complex? I am already struggling to turn the * + - into operators and i don't think eval will help me very far here, will it?

Comment: ` I am already struggling to turn the * + -` can we see the code?

Comment: So what the big deal? You have two versions, with `*` and `+`. It's is trivial to  find `x` that satisfies those equations.

Comment: How would you represent these formulas in JavaScript language? As one string? In that case you'll need to parse the string (difficulty depends on how complex these formulas may become), and the solve the thing. All that is indeed is not trivial. If you can clearly identify what the input will be like, the boundaries of possible expressions, and most importantly, your attempt and where you got stuck with it, then maybe this question is not too broad.

Comment: @trincot well I already do not understand the solution to formula 1 for example. The required input seems to be "+" and x=6. But shouldnt multiply and division be done before adding and substracting?

Comment: If that is what they told you, then indeed that is wrong for the reason you give.

Answer (score 1):

math.js library has math.eval function. Check out [this link](http://mathjs.org/) and [this link](http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html)

```
// provide a scope
var scope = {
   a: 3,
   b: 4
};
math.eval('a * b', scope);              // 12
math.eval('c = 2.3 + 4.5', scope);      // 6.8
scope.c;                                // 6.8
```